# Disabling/Renabling checkboxes on page load in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this has been asked a dozen ways, but I can't get this to work.

Basically, I have 2 checkboxes. On page load one of the two needs to be disabled. When you click the one that is enabled, the page re-loads (makes a service call) and enables the disabled one.

If you click the first enabled checkbox again (to uncheck it), it reloads the page again and should disable the initial one that was disabled on page load. Any ideas?  (The Ax.UserPrefs is just a utility function that drops a var into local storage)

```
  //On page load I have Checkbox 2 being disabled
  $('#admin-user-accounts-show-hide-deleted').prop("disabled", true);

 //Checkbox 1
  $('#admin-user-accounts-show-hide-disabled').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  ax.UserPrefs('preference',$this.is(':checked'));
  if ($this.hasClass('initted')) {
    setTimeout(function() { ax.Routing.Route(); }, 300);  
     $('#admin-user-accounts-show-hide-deleted').prop("disabled", false);
  }
  if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
    setTimeout(function(), 300); 
     $('#admin-user-accounts-show-hide-deleted').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Comment: in your change function, just check the property before set another

Comment: thanks I thought i was doing that but maybe not